# Is the Microsoft implementation of mbstowcs_s thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013

In my application I need thread safe conversion of a multibyte character string to a wide character string. I use `mbstowcs_s` for this purpose. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) I have found a note that some of `mbstowcs_s` implementations are not thread safe but there is nothing about thread safety at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyktyxsx(v=vs.120).aspx).

Is the Microsoft implementation of `mbstowcs_s` thread safe?

Comment: Don't have VS2013 handy at the moment, but IIRC it still ships with the CRT source code.

Comment: why is this marked as C++ this is about a C runtime function? there are better ways to do this in C++ that are safer and guaranteed by the standard to be safe

Comment: @Mgetz: If the OP is writing a C++ program, the question gets tagged [tag:c++]. That's what tags are for: defining the constraints of the solution set.

Comment: @Mgetz: Can you please share your C++ solution?

Comment: Yes, it is thread-safe.  Global variables in the CRT, like the mbstate_t variable in this case, are thread-local.

Comment: A note that [by default locale is global](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235302%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the question is marked as C++ [`<codecvt>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt) is your friend

the following work with:

- VS2010+
- GCC5+

### if your MBCS string is UTF-8:

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>


using utf8converter = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>>;
std::wstring widen(const std::string &to_widen)
{
    return utf8converter{}.from_bytes(to_widen);
}

std::string narrow(const std::wstring &to_narrow)
{
    return utf8converter{}.to_bytes(to_narrow);
}
```

### If the string is some other locale(set on the thread):

```
using locale_converter = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<wchar_t, char, std::mbstate_t>>;

std::wstring widen(const std::string &to_widen)
{
    return locale_converter{}.from_bytes(to_widen);
}

std::string narrow(const std::wstring &to_narrow)
{
    return locale_converter{}.to_bytes(to_narrow);
}
```

As far as I'm aware the locale based ones are also thread safe because they grab a copy of the current thread's locale facet when they are constructed. Given that locale is thread specific it is inherently thread safe anyway...

Comment: Thnx, I will try your solution. I need to be sure it will not cause performance problems.

Comment: I've never had issues with it, but I've also never put it in a place that was an extremely hot path. But for 99% of use cases it should be fine if not potentially faster due to inlining and in the UTF8 case not calling out across DLL boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible ways an implementation can suffer from race conditions. First, it can rely on a single global shared mbstate, and second, it has to query the global locale.

There is a `mbsrtowcs_s` function that takes in an explicit mbstate, which by design cannot have the first problem. There is also a Microsoft-specific `_mbstowcs_s_l` function that takes in an explicit locale, which by design cannot have the second problem. Funnily enough, there is no `_mbsrtowcs_s_l`, because apparently having no possible threading issues is too much to ask for.

The documentation for `mbsrtowcs_s` explicitly calls out the race condition if any other thread calls `setlocale` concurrently, as seen in the links posted by Danh. Unfortunately there seems to be no explicit documentation on whether there is a race condition on the conversion state.

However, Microsoft has traditionally had the distinction between single-threaded and multi-threaded CRT, where the multi-threaded version has thread-local state holding all of the CRT functions' statics that get returned or used internally, making functions like strtok thread-safe, though not fully reentrant. It stands to reason that this applies to `mbstwcs` and its variants as well. Newer versions of Visual Studio don't even have a single-threaded version anymore.

So although I cannot check until I'm back at work on Monday, I'm quite certain that `_mbstowcs_s_l` at least is completely thread-safe.

Comment: Actually, MSDN description of [mbsrtowcs_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08axaf90.aspx) has very strange wording about thread safety condition: `if no function in the current thread calls setlocale as long as this function is executing and the mbstate argument is not a null pointer.` It can be treated as **current (single) thread** calls `mbsrtowcs_s` (with non-NULL `mbstate` argument), then calls `setlocale`, and then calls `mbsrtowcs_s` again. It doesn't say about **other** thread called `setlocale` while given one executing `mbsrtowcs_s`.

Comment: @Sebastian: Thnx for your detailed answer. To sum up your answer, would you recommend to update all of our code to `mbsrtowcs_s` usage to achieve thread safety in string conversion? At the moment we are using `mbstowcs_s`.